# Would a Kawasaki Z900 exhaust fit on a Kawasaki Z250sl?

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, part-interchange

Looking to buy a small slip-on exhaust:

[image]

It's for a Kawasaki Z900, 2017. But would it fit on a Kawasaki Z250sl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a welder, materials, and know how, anything is possible. I'm assuming you are looking for a "slip on" application. If so, this is not the part for you. The Z900 is a 4-cylinder inline engine, which is a completely different exhaust from your Z250 2-cylinder. I'm not sure what part of the exhaust the image you are showing is, but without massaging it through fabrication methods, this is not going to be a very good option for you. More than likely it would cost you more to get it modified than the purchase price of the part itself.

Comment: I see. Great point thank you. It's a 1 cylinder, but that probably makes it even worse. Exhaust link: https://motostyle.dk/shop/z900-aarg-2017-1960p.html?fbclid=IwAR1SE4ugiOzuaTPHDvtvuyYyWRfvUyoZ4-Vji2rMOzW8MmgX9XPINyHWVeg

Comment: @nammerkage - I must have been looking at the wrong model then for your bike. The description I read was stating it had two (even though I thought it would be a single cylinder). No matter. I'm glad you found this answer of use to you.